# Gradient of the composite of a function and the inverse of another

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m \xrightarrow{} \mathbb{R}^m$ and $g: \mathbb{R}^m \xrightarrow{}\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ has inverse $f^{-1}$. What would be the gradient of the composition of $g$ with the inverse of $f$, $\nabla( g \;\circ \; f^{-1})$?

My thoughts are that we have the chain rule for the Jacobian matrix that says that the Jacobian of the composite is the product of the  Jacobian of the outer function evaluated at the inner function with the Jacobian of the inner function, also the Jacobian matrix of the inverse function is simply the inverse of the Jacobian matrix of $f$, the combination of these results would give me

$$ Jg(f(x))(Jf(x))^{-1} $$

Then for any $g: \mathbb{R}^m \xrightarrow{}\mathbb{R}$, $J(g(x))=(\nabla g(x))^{\top}$,

$$ \begin{align}
J(g \;\circ \; f^{-1})  &=  (\nabla g(f(x)))^\top(Jf(x))^{-1} \\
\nabla (g \;\circ \; f^{-1})  &= (\nabla g(f(x))^\top(Jf(x))^{-1})^\top \\  
&= (Jf(x))^{-1})^\top\nabla g(f(x))
\end{align}
$$

I would appreciate insights, thanks in advance.

Comment: g\circ f^{-1} is not well defined

Comment: Corrected the dimensions, sorry.

Comment: now it is correct. You’re formula is right

Comment: Thanks, Federico. Just for context, this appeared for me when studying the moments of a distribution in the m-parameters exponential family. $f$ is the function that maps the parameters into their canonical forms and $g$ is a function that appears into the moment generating function.